# MiKTeX: finding updateable packages takes >45 mins

Tags: updating, repositories

I am in the process of creating a portable LaTeX system. For this I downloaded MiKTeX 2.9 Portable, which I installed and am now trying to update. However, the 'Updateable packages' screen keeps hanging on 'Searching...' without any visible drive, CPU or network activity.

I tried solving this by changing from a random package repository to a specific one. Upon making this change, i got a dialog 'Downloading package database', which exhibits the same problem: doing nothing and not changing.

Trying to update the repository with the option 'Let me choose the repository' (choosing a different location than with the action above) results in the same problem.

Is it normal for this process to take 45 - 60 minutes? Is there something I am doing wrong, or a common problem with making these updates? I tried to find related questions, but all questions I could find are about specific error messages, not about a simply stalling update.

The only thing I can think of that might be wrong is some kind of firewall issue. However, I am trying to execute this update from a PC on which I have a regular version of MiKTeX 2.9 installed, which has no problem finding and installing packages on the fly.

**Edit:** I just found out that I *am* able to manually install packages through the package manager. So it isn't a server/network issue, the problem just arises when trying to update.

Comment: How long is "a really long time"?

Comment: @PaulGessler Fair point. It is 45-60 minutes, which I don't think it needs to take to check for updates frome some server. I have updated the question with the specification.

Comment: Is it always like this or recently happened? Some servers go down without their indexes are dying and keeps MikTeX  high for no reason.

Comment: @percusse this is a recent thing, since I have only today started working on this  system. I don't think it's a server issue; I can manually install packages without a problem.

Comment: A data point: Yesterday I downloaded the "Basic" installer for x64 and it took nearly an hour. However, during the install and subsequent update things proceeded very quickly. I suspect repository issues.

Comment: I am using the portable MikTeX and have no issue provided that I run update when I am not behind my company's firewall. Behind the firewall, MiKTeX times out with an error message.

Comment: @BillMeahan Thanks for your comment, that might be the case. However, I can manually install packages from the same repository that I am trying to update from without problem. So I am not sure if the problem really lies in the repository

Comment: @Sveinung Thanks for the comment. As I wrote in the question, I doubt it is a firewall issue for the same reason I doubt it's a repository issue: manually installing packages works fine.

Comment: @LSchoon I just mention it because it may be helpful to know that it works on somebody's system. I installed the basic version and the first time I compiled one of my documents, the compile took some time because a lot of additional packages had to be downloaded. But nothing near 45 minutes, more like five to ten minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you deliberately select "Let me choose the repository" the updater will attempt to find the "nearest" repository server based on network response time. However, if the repository server is having problems (which could be a result of system maintenance going on), its ability to find and deliver each package requested might be impaired and take far, far longer than the time its network response would indicate. Since it looks for the "nearest" repository every time it is invoked, it may very well use a *different server on every invocation.* Try selecting a repository manually and see what happens.

This is *not* a firewall problem, it is a consequence of an attempt to minimize network bandwidth by choosing the "nearest" repository.

TeX Live caches the first repository it uses and unless you deliberately change it the admin tool will use that repository every time so the results will be consistent although potentially not optimal either.

Comment: Your posting seems to be about TeXLive, whereas the original query was about MikTeX and slowness in its updating process. Could you make your answer address MikTeX aspects as well?

Comment: @mico I think the comment on TeXLive is only by way of contrast to the body of the answer, which deals with MikTeX.

Comment: @PaulStanley - Thanks for this clarification.

Comment: Correct @PaulStanley. The TeXLive reference was simply to contrast the way two different distributions deal with choosing a repository for an action. Neither way is "right" and neither way is "wrong" they are simply different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I tried updating from several manually selected repositories. All with the same result: nothing :-(

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem with the portable version on my flashdrive.  From my experiences, I discovered that the update time did not depend on either the internet or the computer speed.  That being said and based on what you have told us, I would say that there is probably something wrong with your program or your device.
So, if I were you, I would delete your current version of the portable LaTeX and try reinstalling it.  If that does not work, I would make sure that the device you are using is not damaged.